# How can I have XPath ignore nested nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

There's probably a better way to do this than what I'd doing, because 
I'm stuck in a metaphorical pothole.

I want to get some of the nodes beneath a particular node.  I came up 
with this XPath expression:

```
>>> content_tags = 'h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 p ol ul dl table'.split() 
>>> content_xpath = './/*[%s]' % ' or '.join('self::%s' % i for i in content_tags) 
>>> content_xpath 
'.//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or 
self::h6 or self::p or self::ol or self::ul or self::dl or 
self::table]'
```

Any of the listed content_tags can be the top of the hierarchy I'd 
wanting, and I want to ignore other elements that may be at the same 
or higher levels.  Unfortunately, sometimes there's a `<p>` inside a 
`<ul>` or a `<table>`, or a `<table>` inside a `<ol>`, etc., and I get the 
inner element as a separate result along with the outer.  Is there a good way to 
perform a "cut" to ignore nodes that may be nested inside one that 
I've found?  Or is there some better way of doing this that I'm 
somehow missing?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to parse.

```
<div class="interesting"> 
<img src="ignore-this.jpg"/> 
<h1>I want this.</h1> 
<p>I want this, too.</p> 
<div class="sidebar"> 
<ul> 
<li><p>I only want one copy of this, inside the UL.</p></li> 
<li><p>Ditto.</p></li> 
</ul> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Thanks!

BTW, I found a few posts on a w3.org mailing list that advocated a 
"dont-include- any-descendant-or-self" filter, which I think would do 
exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to have made it into the 
final spec.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching as with `//p` is explicitly recursive -- if that's not what you want, don't do that! :)

If you only want a `p` that's directly under an interesting `div`, but that `div` can be anywhere in your hierarchy, this would be expressed as such:

```
//div[@class='interesting']/p
```

...if you only want a `p` that's directly under the location in your tree the search is relative to, that's even simpler:

```
./p
```

Comment: I didn't really want to do things this way, but you've talked me into it.  Now I need to figure out how to remove the elements I don't want (e.g., all `<img>` elements), no matter how deeply nested.

Comment: @samwyse if you want to be able to _remove_ things, perhaps an XQuery implementation with the XQUF (XQuery Update Facility) extensions would be the right tool.